# Adjust image to content size

Tags: html, css, image

I would like to adjust my images to the size of the content. In some columns the image is too big in comparison to the content. In the following [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/0Lvfstx7/) is the example

After several trial and error I can solve the problem by just giving the `div` containing the image a `background-image` but I want to avoid this solution as I would like to have an actual image with an alt title for SEO reasons. Here is my desired result (but with an actual image, not a `background-image`

```css
.col-4 {width: 33.33%;}
.col-8 {width: 66.66%;}

*{
 box-sizing: border-box;
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
}

*::before, *::after {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

[class*="col-"]{
 float: left;
}

.row {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: wrap;
}

.row::after {
    content: "";
    clear: both;
    display: block;
}

#services .row{
 background-color: #1AC4F8;
 margin-bottom: 30px;
}

#services .col-4{
  background-image:url("http://truck-art-project.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/09/CARRUSEL-TRUCK-SIXE_EN.jpg");
  background-size:cover;
}

#services .col-8{
 padding: 20px 20px;
}

#services .col-8 > *{
 color: white;
 margin: 0 0 20px 0;
}
```

```html
<section id="services">
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-8">
     <h3>Przeprowadzki krajowe i międzynarodowe</h3>
     <p>Nasza firma transportowa oferuje usługi przeprowadzki na terenie całego kraju jak również poza granicami na terenie całej Europy. Prosimy o kontakt w celu otrzymania indywidualnej wyceny.</p>
   </div>
   <div class="col-4"></div>
</div>
<div class="row">
   <div class="col-4"></div>
   <div class="col-8">
      <h3>Taksówka bagażowa</h3>
  </div>
</div>
</section>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hope this is what you are looking for. 
The size of the image could be changed by yourself. 
You can use an image with a src and alt, and can add some information next to it.

```css
body, html {
  background: white;
    -ms-box-sizing: border-box;
    -o-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

.item--wrapper {
  background: #EFEFEF;
  padding: 10px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  width: calc(100% - 20px);
  margin-bottom: 5px;
}

.info--wrapper {
  width: calc(100% - 70px);
}

.item--wrapper,
.image--wrapper,
.info--wrapper,
.button--wrapper,
.info--core, 
.item--image {
  vertical-align: middle;
  display: inline-block;
}

.item--image {
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
}

.info--core {
  width: calc(100% - 20px);
  padding: 0 10px;
}
```

```html
<div id="item1" class="item--wrapper">
  <div class="image--wrapper">
    <img src="http://truck-art-project.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/09/CARRUSEL-TRUCK-SIXE_EN.jpg" class="item--image">
  </div>
  <div class="info--wrapper">
    <div class="info--core">
      <h3>Przeprowadzki krajowe i międzynarodowe</h3>
      <p>Nasza firma transportowa oferuje usługi przeprowadzki na terenie całego kraju jak również poza granicami na terenie całej Europy. Prosimy o kontakt w celu otrzymania indywidualnej wyceny.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div id="item2" class="item--wrapper">
  <div class="info--wrapper">
    <div class="info--core">
      <h3>Przeprowadzki krajowe i międzynarodowe</h3>
      <p>Nasza firma transportowa oferuje usługi przeprowadzki na terenie całego kraju jak również poza granicami na terenie całej Europy. Prosimy o kontakt w celu otrzymania indywidualnej wyceny.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="image--wrapper">
    <img src="http://truck-art-project.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/09/CARRUSEL-TRUCK-SIXE_EN.jpg" class="item--image">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for your effort, but it is not what I'm looking for. I have edited my question showing the result I'm searching for, but with an actual image, not a `background-image`

Comment: Why do you want to cut the image ? Or do you want to stretch it ?

Comment: I don't mind if the image is cutted but I don't want to have a big image and small content. I want the image to adapt to the content size.

Comment: You could try to use `position: absolute` on the image and `relative` on the wrapper, as well you need to use `overflow: hidden`

Answer (score 0):

You could use bootstrap **grid system**, make it really simple (for sure you could make your own, define the width, but also you need few media query to define width in different screen size)

Include Bootstrap CSS to your project, or take some source code from it and make your own.

> ### REF: http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid
>
> [image]

```css
.col-4 {
  width: 33.33%;
}

.col-8 {
  width: 66.66%;
}

* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

*::before,
*::after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

[class*="col-"] {
  float: left;
}

.row {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: wrap;
}

.row::after {
  content: "";
  clear: both;
  display: block;
}

#services .row {
  background-color: #1AC4F8;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
}

#services .col-8 {
  padding: 20px 20px;
}

#services .col-8>* {
  color: white;
  margin: 0 0 20px 0;
}

#services img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<section id="services">
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>


  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-8 col-md-10">
      <h3>Przeprowadzki krajowe i międzynarodowe</h3>
      <p>Nasza firma transportowa oferuje usługi przeprowadzki na terenie całego kraju jak również poza granicami na terenie całej Europy. Prosimy o kontakt w celu otrzymania indywidualnej wyceny.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-4 col-md-2">
      <img src="http://truck-art-project.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/09/CARRUSEL-TRUCK-SIXE_EN.jpg" alt="our services">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-4 col-md-2">
      <img src="http://truck-art-project.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/09/CARRUSEL-TRUCK-SIXE_EN.jpg" alt="our services">
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-8 col-md-10">
      <h3>Taksówka bagażowa</h3>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: Thank you for the tip, I've been working with it for quite a time. Nevertheless, I can't manage to solve the stated issue with bootstrap grid system. In the second column the image doesn't adapt to the content size yet.

Comment: @Alvarado87 I didn't update the 2nd row just to let you see the difference, check the updated code, should all fit now =D

Comment: Thanks for your help but that's not what I'm looking for :( I want the image and the text to be aligned in the same row, not one on top of another. Regarding Bootstrap I know it's faster, but I'm just learning web design and for the time being I would like to learn more about the in and outs of code writing; after that I would consider using it.